# Rails - How to loop through association of an object in Grid class which is using DataGrid gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid

I'm using [DataGrid gem](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) to display data in table and it can be sorted. It works well with object's fields. My problem is that I want to display data of its associated object, but I cannot.

I have tried something like:

```
column(:myFieldName, html: true) do |object|
   object.assocated_objects.each do |a_obj|
      a_object.a_object_field
   end
end
```

Unluckily, this doesn't work. It always returns associated_objects as collection of objects.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
dynamic do
 object.assocated_objects.each do |a_obj|
   column(:myFieldName, html: true) do |object|
     a_object.a_object_field
   end
 end
end
```

You can see more on [Dynamic Columns](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Columns#dynamic-columns)

Comment: ! Thanks for your answer. Anyway, I've already tried that way as well but it doesn't help as I don't understand what they do something like: `def account
    Account.find(account_id)
  end`